# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tempat_lahir' cannot be null

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

i try to make update profile from user
so firstly i will make insert for tempat_lahir

this my controller

```
public function getUpdateProfile()
{
    return view('update_profile');
}

public function postUpdateProfile(Request $request)
{
    User::create([
        'tempat_lahir'  => $request->tempat_lahir,
   ]);
```

this my migrations

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('tempat_lahir');
    });
}
```

this my User.php

```
protected $fillable = [
    'tempat_lahir'
];
```

this my web.php

```
Route::get('/update_profile', 'AuthController@getUpdateProfile')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/update_profile', 'AuthController@postUpdateProfile')->name('update_profile')->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide information about the blade file and the form you're submitting. Have you set the name for the input?

Comment: Error says you are trying to insert `NULL` in `tempat_lahir` column, which is not allowed.

Comment: Both your posted routes have the same method and path? Only one of them will actually be available. I'm guessing the second one should be ::post() instead of ::get()?

Answer (score 2):

you just have to edit migration file

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('tempat_lahir')->nullable();
    });
}
```

and fresh the laravel migration

or edit the `tempat_lahir` column in database to add `nullable` attribute;

Also you should edit `RegisterController.php` for give data form to fill `tempat_lahir` column